# Get Direct Message Reply in Twitter api

Tags: c#, twitter

I want to get Direct Messages From the Twitter Accounts I have logged in...when i am using '

```
https://api.twitter.com/1/direct_messages.json?count=50&since_id=228011290508013568&include_entities=true
```

i am getting error :-

> {"error":"Could not authenticate you.","request":"/1/direct_messages.json?count=50&since_id=228011290508013568&include_entities=true"}

i am not able to authenticate my request please Help........

Comment: Have you already got your keys from Twitter? Which library are you using to sign your requests?

Answer (score 0):

Did you do what Terence Eden said ? Do you follow the Twitter process for authenticated requests : https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/authorizing-request ?